# Difference between object and object created using class

Tags: javascript, class, object, this

```
    var cat = {
     name: "Gus",
     color: "gray",
     age: 15,
     printInfo: function() {
      console.log("Name:", this.name, "Color:", this.color, "Age:", this.age); 
       nestedFunction = function() {
         console.log("Name:", this.name, "Color:", this.color, "Age:", this.age)
       }
       nestedFunction();
     }
    }
    cat.printInfo()
```

//PRINTS : Name: Gus Color: gray Age: 15 -- Printed by printInfo

//PRINTS : Name: undefined Color: undefined Age: undefined -- Printed by nestedFunction

```
    class info {
     constructor(name,color,age){
     this.name = name
     this.color = color
     this.age = age
    }
    printInfo = function(){
      console.log("Name:", this.name, "Color:", this.color, "Age:", this.age); 
      nestedFunction=function(){
        console.log("Name:", this.name, "Color:", this.color, "Age:", this.age); 
      }
      nestedFunction();  
     }
    }
    var obj=new info("thomas","orange","26") 
    obj.printInfo()
```

//PRINTS : Name: thomas Color: orange Age: 26 (Printed by printInfo)

ReferenceError: nestedFunction is not defined (It throws error after that)
In the first case direct object is made and in the case 2 object is made using class.

But the output is different
In the class object it throws error as **nestedFunction is not defined**

Please tell me the difference between direct object and object made using class template.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you forgot the **var** before the declaration of **nestedFunction** and when you give **this** as an argument to that function, then in both cases your code works:

```
var nestedFunction = function(cat) {
    console.log("Name:", cat.name, "Color:", cat.color, "Age:", cat.age)
}
nestedFunction(this);
```

By the way: in the second case it is much cleaner to avoid the usage of a class, the *new* keyword and their side effects, and to use instead your object from the first case with behavior delegation:

```
var cat = {
    setData(name, color, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
        this.age = age;
    },
    printInfo: function() {
        console.log("Name:", this.name, "Color:", this.color, "Age:", this.age); 
        var nestedFunction = function(cat) {
            console.log("Name:", cat.name, "Color:", cat.color, "Age:", cat.age)
        }
        nestedFunction(this);
    }
}

var gus = Object.create(cat);        //behavior delegation
var thomas = Object.create(cat);     //behavior delegation

gus.setData("Gus", "gray", 15);
thomas.setData("thomas", "orange", 26);

gus.printInfo();                     //Name: Gus Color: gray Age: 15
                                     //Name: Gus Color: gray Age: 15
thomas.printInfo();                  //Name: thomas Color: orange Age: 26
                                     //Name: thomas Color: orange Age: 26
```